# Django "The submitted file is empty"

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have used multiple FileFields in a model and my app gives error "The submitted file is empty" on execution, folowing are the details of my code:

My models.py:

```
class KBCTest(models.Model):
algorithm = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
entityFile = models.FileField(blank=False,
                              upload_to=updateFilename,
                              validators=[validateTestingFileExtension])
relationFile = models.FileField(blank=False,
                                upload_to=updateFilename,
                                validators=[validateTestingFileExtension])
```

My forms.py

```
class KBCTestForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = KBCTest
    fields = ('algorithm', 'entityFile', 'relationFile')

def clean(self):
    super(KBCTestForm, self).clean()
    data = self.cleaned_data
    return data
```

My views.py:

```
def testing(request):
title = 'Testing'
template = 'testing.html'
form = ''

if request.method == 'GET':
    form = KBCTestForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = KBCTestForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        runAlgo = Run(form.cleaned_data)
        runAlgo.configAndTest()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning', kwargs={'function': 'testing'}))

context = {'title': title, 'form': form}
return render(request, template, context)
```

My template:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <div class='col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4'>
            <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
            <!-- If form not rendered(i.e. views context) don't show submit button -->
            {% if form %}
                <!-- Use 'csrf_token' to prevent cross-site forgery -->
                <form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST', action=''>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form|crispy }} </br>
                    {{ form.non_field_errors|crispy }}
                <input type='submit' value='Test' class='btn btn-default'/>
                </form>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

When I run this template it fails to validate the form and gives error "The submitted file is empty" error as visible in the screenshot below:
[image: Result after pressing the button]

Comment: Are the files you're uploading actually not empty -i.e., do they have a file size greater than 0?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#filefield) part of the Django docs, where it mentions the parameter `allow_empty_file` for the `forms.FileField`. Maybe it gives you a few clues.

Note: I'm not exactly sure how this applies to `ModelForm` or `Model.FileField`.